# How do I do something when an element is scrolled to the vertical middle of the viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I'm trying to create video-highlighting functionality like [this page](http://www.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/07/21/silk-road/). As each video scrolls into the center of the page, that video is highlighted. But, instead of their site's map content on the right sidebar, each video's title/description would become highlighted and vertically centered. Like so:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/annablabber/gw9yoq06/4/

**HTML**

```
<div class="videos-container">
  <ul class="video-info">
    <li><div class="title">Title of video</div><div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div></li>
    <li><div class="title">Title of video</div><div class="description">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div></li>
    <li><div class="title">Title of video</div><div class="description">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div></li>
    <li><div class="title">Title of video</div><div class="description">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident.</div></li>
    <li><div class="title">Title of video</div><div class="description">sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div></li>
    <li><div class="title">Title of video</div><div class="description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</div></li>
    <li><div class="title">Title of video</div><div class="description">Totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</div></li>
    <li><div class="title">Title of video</div><div class="description">Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</div></li>
    <li><div class="title">Title of video</div><div class="description">Neque porro quisquam est.</div></li>
    <li><div class="title">Title of video</div><div class="description">Qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur.</div></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="videos">
    <div class="video-container"><video poster="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/07/21/silk-road/assets/media/driveby_970.jpg" preload="auto" src="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/07/21/silk-road/assets/media/driveby_970.mp4" loop></video></div>
    <div class="video-container"><video poster="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/07/21/silk-road/assets/media/driveby_970.jpg" preload="auto" src="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/07/21/silk-road/assets/media/driveby_970.mp4" loop></video></div>
    <div class="video-container"><video poster="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/07/21/silk-road/assets/media/driveby_970.jpg" preload="auto" src="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/07/21/silk-road/assets/media/driveby_970.mp4" loop></video></div>
    <div class="video-container"><video poster="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/07/21/silk-road/assets/media/driveby_970.jpg" preload="auto" src="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/07/21/silk-road/assets/media/driveby_970.mp4"></video></div>
    <div class="video-container"><video poster="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/07/21/silk-road/assets/media/driveby_970.jpg" preload="auto" src="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/07/21/silk-road/assets/media/driveby_970.mp4"></video></div>
    <div class="video-container"><video poster="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/07/21/silk-road/assets/media/driveby_970.jpg" preload="auto" src="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/07/21/silk-road/assets/media/driveby_970.mp4"></video></div>
    <div class="video-container"><video poster="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/07/21/silk-road/assets/media/driveby_970.jpg" preload="auto" src="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/07/21/silk-road/assets/media/driveby_970.mp4"></video></div>
    <div class="video-container"><video poster="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/07/21/silk-road/assets/media/driveby_970.jpg" preload="auto" src="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/07/21/silk-road/assets/media/driveby_970.mp4"></video></div>
    <div class="video-container"><video poster="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/07/21/silk-road/assets/media/driveby_970.jpg" preload="auto" src="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/07/21/silk-road/assets/media/driveby_970.mp4"></video></div>
    <div class="video-container"><video poster="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/07/21/silk-road/assets/media/driveby_970.jpg" preload="auto" src="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/07/21/silk-road/assets/media/driveby_970.mp4"></video></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/**
 * Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0 (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)
 * http://cssreset.com
 */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/* End CSS reset */

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.videos-container {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}


.video-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 33px;
  background-color: #000;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: .4;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s;
  transiton: opacity .5s;
}

video.highlighted {
  opacity: 1;
}

.video-info {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 240px;
}

.video-info li {
  opacity: .7;
  margin-bottom: 27px;
}

.video-info li .title {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.video-info li .description {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 180%;
  letter-spacing: .04em;
  display: none;
}

.video-info li.highlighted {
  margin-bottom: 56px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.video-info li.highlighted .title  {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  letter-spacing: .03em;
}

.video-info li.highlighted .description  {
  display: block;
}
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
  return ((docViewTop < elemTop) && (docViewBottom > elemBottom));
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('video').each(function() {
    if (isScrolledIntoView(this)) {

      // Find out which video it is
      var currentIndex = $('video').index(this); 
      // Highlight the associated video title/description
      $(".video-info li:eq(" + currentIndex + ")").addClass("highlighted").attr('id', 'rectangle'); 

      // Vertically center highlighted video title/description
      var viewportCenter = $(window).height() / 2;
      var rect = document.getElementById("rectangle").getBoundingClientRect();
      var liCenter = rect.top + $("li.highlighted").height()/2;
      var verticalDifference = viewportCenter - liCenter;
      $(".video-info").css("-webkit-transform", "translateY(" + verticalDifference + "px)");

      // Remove 'highlighted' class from other videos
      $("video").removeClass('highlighted'); 
      // Add 'highlighted' to this video 
      $(this).addClass('highlighted'); 
      // Play this video
      $(this).get(0).play(); 

    } else {
      // Remove 'highlighted' class on video 
      $(this).removeClass('highlighted');
      // Pause video  
      $(this).get(0).pause();
      // Pause video    
      var currentIndex = $('video').index(this);
      $(".video-info li:eq(" + currentIndex + ")").removeClass("highlighted");

    }
  });
});
```

The video-highlighting and description-highlighting CSS styles and jQuery work great, but there are a few **problems**:

- Every time you scroll, the highlighted video title/description transforms up and down from its original position to its "translateY" position in a rather seizure-inducing manner.
- Multiple videos are getting highlighted at a time if your viewport is tall, since multiple videos are "scrolled into view". I was thinking of fixing this by specifying that the video has to be touching the invisible vertical center line through the page. Not sure how to go about this!

Any ideas on **how to tweak my code so that**:

1. The video closest to the vertical middle of the viewport is highlighted (**only one** video at a time)
2. That video's associated title/description is highlighted, and
3. The title/description moves to the vertical center of the viewport?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check out ScrollSpy in the Bootstrap project: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: use Waypoints https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints `$('#example-offset-percent').waypoint(function() {
console.log('50% from the top');
}, { offset: '50%' });`

Comment: @miro omg. Waypoints is awesome and solves my problem. Thanks yo!